# Which of the following phrases is correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Which phrase is correct: "Nice to hearing from you again" or "nice to hearing you again?"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Neither. Correct is:

> Nice to hear from you again.

There are two things to notice here:

The present participle of the verb (ending in *-ing*) should not be preceded by the infinitive marker *to*, and after the infinitive marker *to* you should always use the base form of the verb. So it should always be *Nice **to hear*** and never *Nice **to hearing***.

Also, there is a difference between *to hear* and *to hear from*. The verb *to hear* just means that you can literally hear and understand what the other person is saying. The phrase *to hear from* means to start or renew a social relationship with someone. In this case, you're trying to say that it was nice to speak with someone again, and you're not focusing on the physical act of hearing, so you want to say "Nice to hear from you".

Comment: @JSBangs: So, "Hello! Nice to hear from you again! How are you?" is correct. Am I right?

Comment: @misho, yes, that sentence is exactly right.

Comment: But `nice hearing from you again` would be correct?

Comment: @Trufa, yes, that's another possible variation.

Comment: @JSBangs: I was just mentioned it because I though it was similar to the OP's proposal...

Comment: @Trufa: Was that intended to be a joke? ;)

Comment: @AdamRobinson: no no joke at all... The OP asked if `nice to hearing from you again` is correct, and @JSBangs correctly answered, that no it isn't so, I just pointed out that if you removed the `to` the phrase would be correct. @JSBangs doesn't contradict that but does not say it explicitly, so I did.

Comment: @Trufa: I was referring to your use of "mentioned" rather than "mentioning" in your response; given the subject at hand (conjugated vs. participle) and the fact that your response confused the two, it could have been intended as a joke.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: haha no, an honest mistake, ironic huh? :)

Comment: @Trufa: That's what I figured, hence the smiley ;)

Comment: @AdamRobinson: :)

Comment: Keep in mind that there is an implied "It is" or some other tense of "it [to be]" at the beginning of the phrase.

Answer (score 5):

In English we would say

> Nice to be hearing from you again.

Note the "be" in there.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use *hearing*, then say:

> Nice hearing from you again.

This is quite common in email, phone conversation, or regular talk.

Otherwise, say:

> Nice to hear from you again.

You could also say:

> Nice to hear your voice again.

Comment: Worth noting that "Nice to hear your voice again." is a bit more intimate. Not something you'd say to just any acquaintance.